# How to convert large (2gb+) .key to .pptx?

Tags: windows, osx

I've tried the usual options: upload to icloud (choked), online converters (said too big and I should purchase an account). I need to convert a large .key (apple keynote) to .pptx presentation. How do I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: What version of Keynote was your file produced by? Are you looking for a free tool, or do you have a budget?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like **[howtos](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185),** etc. If you're looking for software, please see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) and adjust your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Why not try Keynote itself?

1. Open the original file
2. Choose File > Export to...
3. Select the Power Point Tab
4. Set your options including Power Point .pptx format
5. Click Next
6. Enter a filename & select a location
7. Click Export